# Dynamically change log level for every class in a specific package

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j

I'm working on a project that uses SLF4J + Logback, and I was hoping to find a way to configure the log level of different scopes by using a REST API call. The call takes in an object with the scope (class, package, or root path) and the desired logging level. Each class in my project that has a logger uses a static Logback logger.

I used other Stack Overflow answers & the Logback manual to find the solution to change the logging level for a single class:

```java
LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
Logger target = loggerContext.getLogger(DESIRED_CLASS_PATH);
target.setLevel(DESIRED_LOGGING_LEVEL);
```

This works for that class. However, I tried to use the root logger to change all of the loggers for all of the classes in my project, using this:

```java
Logger rootLogger = loggerContext.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
rootLogger.setLevel(DESIRED_LOGGING_LEVEL);
```

This only changes the root logger, and when I try to print out the log level for any class inside the project, it is not the desired logging level. I tried declaring a logger in the logback.xml file that declared a package logger (the package in which all of my classes and subpackages are contained) and tried modifying that to change the subclass loggers, but this did not work. Here is my logback.xml file:

```xml
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

    <logger name="my.uppermost.package" level="info" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

Am I misunderstanding the code or abilities of Logback? If not, is there a way in which I could enter in a package path to my REST API call and update ALL of the loggers for the classes contained in that package?

Answer (score 4):

You can get the list of existing logger and filter them by name :

```java
LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();

for(logger : loggerContext.getLoggerList()) {
 if(logger.getName().startWith("my.target.package.")) {
  logger.setLevel(DESIRED_LOGGING_LEVEL);
 }
}
```

Note that it will change the log level only of logger that already exist. If some object in my.target.package register a logger later, its log level will be whatever is configured in logback.xml

Answer (score 0):

> This only changes the root logger, and when I try to print out the log level for any class inside the project, it is not the desired logging level

Please note that `Logger#getEffectiveLevel`, instead of `Logger#getLevel` is the actual level used for filtering the log.

---

Referring to [Effective Level aka Level Inheritance](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/architecture.html#effectiveLevel):

> If a given logger is not assigned a level, then it inherits one from its closest ancestor with an assigned level. More formally:
>
> > The effective level for a given logger L, is equal to the first non-null level in its hierarchy, starting at L itself and proceeding upwards in the hierarchy towards the root logger.

And referring to source code of `Logger` [`setLevel`](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/Logger.java#L166) and [handleParentLevelChange](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/61ffd3aba042bbb22f588599ff5574d3b9667d22/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/Logger.java#L187), calling `setLevel` of the package logger will set "Effective Level" of the logger inside if log level of those loggers is not set.
If log level is already set in those logger, [Thibault Urien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51385554/logback-dynamically-change-log-level-for-every-class-in-a-specific-package#answer-67401811) will do the job.

Above behavior can be illustrated by following example.
*LoggerLevelNotSet* class with logger level not set

```java
package com.logback.logger;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class LoggerLevelNotSet {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerLevelNotSet.class);

    public static void log() {
        logger.trace("TRACE");
        logger.debug("DEBUG");
        logger.info("TRACE");
        logger.warn("WARN");
        logger.error("ERROR");
    }
}
```

*LoggerLevelNotSet* class with logger level set

```java
package com.logback.logger;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class LoggerLevelSet {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerLevelSet.class);

    public static void log() {
        logger.trace("TRACE");
        logger.debug("DEBUG");
        logger.info("TRACE");
        logger.warn("WARN");
        logger.error("ERROR");
    }
}
```

*logback.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">

    <appender name="stdout"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.logback.logger"
            additivity="false" level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.logback.logger.LoggerLevelSet"
            additivity="false" level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
    </logger>

    <root>
        <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

*TestSetLoggerLevel* main class

```java
package com.logback.logger;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class TestSetLoggerLevel {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestSetLoggerLevel.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        logger.error("Before set level");
        logLevel(loggerContext.getLogger("com.logback.logger.LoggerLevelNotSet"));
        logLevel(loggerContext.getLogger("com.logback.logger.LoggerLevelSet"));
        LoggerLevelNotSet.log();
        LoggerLevelSet.log();
        loggerContext.getLogger("com.logback.logger").setLevel(Level.ERROR);
        logger.error("After set level");
        logLevel(loggerContext.getLogger("com.logback.logger.LoggerLevelNotSet"));
        logLevel(loggerContext.getLogger("com.logback.logger.LoggerLevelSet"));
        LoggerLevelNotSet.log();
        LoggerLevelSet.log();
    }

    private static void logLevel(ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger log) {
        logger.error("{} level: {} effective level:{}", log.getName(), log.getLevel(), log.getEffectiveLevel());
    }
}
```

*Result*

```
ERROR c.logback.logger.TestSetLoggerLevel - Before set level
ERROR c.logback.logger.TestSetLoggerLevel - com.logback.logger.LoggerLevelNotSet level: null effective level:TRACE
ERROR c.logback.logger.TestSetLoggerLevel - com.logback.logger.LoggerLevelSet level: WARN effective level:WARN
TRACE com.logback.logger.LoggerLevelNotSet - TRACE
DEBUG com.logback.logger.LoggerLevelNotSet - DEBUG
INFO  com.logback.logger.LoggerLevelNotSet - TRACE
WARN  com.logback.logger.LoggerLevelNotSet - WARN
ERROR com.logback.logger.LoggerLevelNotSet - ERROR
WARN  com.logback.logger.LoggerLevelSet - WARN
ERROR com.logback.logger.LoggerLevelSet - ERROR
ERROR c.logback.logger.TestSetLoggerLevel - After set level
ERROR c.logback.logger.TestSetLoggerLevel - com.logback.logger.LoggerLevelNotSet level: null effective level:ERROR
ERROR c.logback.logger.TestSetLoggerLevel - com.logback.logger.LoggerLevelSet level: WARN effective level:WARN
ERROR com.logback.logger.LoggerLevelNotSet - ERROR
WARN  com.logback.logger.LoggerLevelSet - WARN
ERROR com.logback.logger.LoggerLevelSet - ERROR
```